# Learning about father's WWII US Army military experience

Tags: united-states, military-records, world-war-2

I know he started as a bugler, he was in transportation and served in Italy and maybe ended the war in Germany. He was discharged as a second lieutenant. He also spent at least 20 years in the Army Reserve.

Where should I look to find out what unit he was in, his job, promotions, etc?